# How to remove null keys from JSON Object

Tags: java

I have the below JSON , i need to remove all the keys which have null value

I have tried this

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Remove {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String str = "{\r\n" + 
            "       \"videos\": {\r\n" + 
            "   
            "       }}";
        JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONObject allKeys_json=    json_obj.getJSONObject("videos");
        Iterator<String> keys = allKeys_json.keys();
        while( keys.hasNext() ) {
        String keyanme = (String)keys.next();
        String keyvalue = allKeys_json.getString(keyanme);
        if(keyvalue.contains("null"))
        {
            System.out.println(keyanme+"\t"+keyvalue);
            json_obj.remove(keyanme);
        }
        }
    System.out.println(allKeys_json);
    }
}
```

but the actual  json is unaffected , could you please tell me how to do this .

Comment: You could try: `JSONObject  putOpt(String name, Object value)`
Equivalent to put(name, value) when both parameters are non-null; does nothing otherwise.

Comment: `org.json.JSONObject` is from what API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only about manipulating a string which structure you know well a solution would be to use some regex

```
str.replaceAll(".*\": null(,)?\\r\\n", "");
```

It could be easier to find a good regex than to invest time in building a model that could be used by Jackson.

Three notes:

- the code above doesn't figure out which is the last line and adapt the json accordingly.
- the pattern should be compiled separately.
- org.json is very inefficient compared to Jackson.

Comment: @NikunjParadva as mentionned in my answer :-)

Comment: Yes but got any solutions?

Comment: @NikunjParadva you could try this regex I just googled https://kaspars.net/blog/dev/regex-remove-all-line-breaks-from-text or google for another one. Let me know once you find the solution. The answer here is that using a Json manipulation library would be more cumbersome than manipulating the json string with a regex.

Comment: Sure i ll try and inform you soon

Answer (score 1):

Check your null value like this

```
if(keyvalue == null)
```

This fixex the issue

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create an model class which is corresponding to the JSON string.

Add

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

to your model class such as

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
public class Video  {
    //the properties
}
```

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson API and use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) on your model/DTO class to remove.

Like

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Video  {
    //the properties
}
```

Comment: _Use Jackson API_ it is a bit extrem to redirect to a different API (if I am not mistaken, this doesn't look like Jackson) just to remove Null value ;-)

Answer (score 0):

thx!

Here is an improved regex expression that also works for an **formatted** and **unformatted** JSON string:

```
 str.replaceAll(" *\"\\w+\"*:(\\s)?null(,)?(\\r)?(\\n)?", "");
```

Answer (score -2):

I used it like this and it worked for me.

```
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
```